# Azure Blob Storage or Azure File Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-files

Looking for suggestions to use the right storage account in Azure.
The use case is to store large number of .zip files which will have 100's of PDF files.
Application will have to upload these .zip files to the storage system and also read from this storage system for processing.

Could you please suggest what is the right option to go for?
Azure Blob or Azure File

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Blob Storage or Azure Files in this scenario may come down to the method available to your application to upload/process the .zip files. If your application is able to use the SDK or upload the file using HTTPS, then this will be the less expensive and more flexible option. If your application/processes are only able to upload files via standard file protocol/commands or target a UNC path, then Azure Files would be a better fit.

Comment: Thanks @Mike for the valuable comments. Yes the application can use HTTPS or can use any SDK. Will the files in Blob storage can be read from a standalone application running on a Jetty server in a VM? In my case the uploaded files will be consumed by a different application that runs on a VM in azure as a standalone application.

Answer (score 1):

You can see examples of when to use one or the other in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-introduction#example-scenarios).

To me this sounds like a Blob Storage scenario.
Unless you need to connect this storage to VMs as a file share, I don't see a reason to use Azure Files for this.

Comment: Thanks @juunasfor the valuable comments. Can the files in Blob storage be read by a standalone application running on a Jetty server in a VM in Azure? In my case the uploaded files will be consumed by a different application that runs on a VM in azure as a standalone application.

Comment: Yes, using the Blob Storage SDKs. Jetty sounds like Java? This is the official library: https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.azure/azure-storage-blob/12.10.2/jar

Comment: Documentation for the library: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/java/api/overview/azure/storage-blob-readme?view=azure-java-stable