# azureml register datastore file share or blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-files, azureml-python-sdk

I have a folder called data with a bunch of csvs (about 80), file sizes are fairly small. This data is clean and has already been preprocessed. I want to upload this data folder and register as a datastore in azureml. Which would be best for this scenario data store created with file share or a data store created with blob storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AFAIK**, based on your scenario you can make use of **`Azure File Share`** to create data store.

Please **note** that, Azure Blob storage is suitable for uploading large amount of unstructured data whereas **`Azure File Share`** is suitable for uploading and processing the structured files in chunks (more interaction with app to share files).

> I have a folder called data with a bunch of csvs (about 80), file sizes are fairly small. This data is clean and has already been preprocessed.

As you mentioned **`CSV`** data is clean and preprocessed it comes under structured data. So, you can make you of **Azure File Share** to create data store.

To register a data store with **Azure File Share** you can make use of this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.datastore.datastore?view=azure-ml-py#azureml-core-datastore-datastore-register-azure-file-share)

To know more about Azure File Share and Azure Blob storage, please find below **links**:

[Azure Blob Storage or Azure File Storage by Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67217164/azure-blob-storage-or-azure-file-storage)

[azureml.data.azure_storage_datastore.AzureFileDatastore class - Azure Machine Learning Python | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.azure_storage_datastore.azurefiledatastore?view=azure-ml-py)